# SVG percentage coordinate is off

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive

I have three SVGs nested inside another SVG. The first one is supposed to be fluid and stretched out so `preserveAspectRatio` is `none`. The other two are set to `10%` and `90%` for the `x` value. But if you resize the page you'll see they have different distance from the left and right side. Why?

I'm expecting to see the left one having the same distance from left as the right one having the distance from right.

```css
.box {
  width: 60vw;
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="50">
    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 2 2" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect x="0" width="2" height="1" fill="#DDDDDD" />
    </svg>

    <svg x="10%" viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#7FDBFF" />
    </svg>

    <svg x="90%" viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#7FDBFF" />
    </svg>
    
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're starting to draw the second blue box at 90%, when you really want to end the draw at 90%. Fix this by setting the viewBox of the second blue box to:

```
viewBox="20 0 20 20"
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured right after. A better option is to set the first value of all `viewBox`es to half of the width. `viewBox="5 0 20 20"`, then they all get rendered from center.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution.

The two blue SVGs are identical apart from their `preserveAspectRatio` attributes.

```css
.box {
  width: 60vw;
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="50">
    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 2 2" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect x="0" width="2" height="1" fill="#DDDDDD" />
    </svg>

    <svg x="10%" width="80%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 10 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#7FDBFF" />
    </svg>

    <svg x="10%" width="80%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 10 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#7FDBFF" />
    </svg>

  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but it will get tricky if I have more than three boxes. e.g. at `10%`, `20%`, `30%` and `90%`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone as confused as me, here is the problem:

[image: screen]

If I set the `viewBox` `x` value to half of the width `10 / 2 = 5`, then I technically panned the origin to the width's center.

```css
.box {
  width: 60vw;
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="50">
    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 2 2" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect x="0" width="2" height="1" fill="#DDDDDD" />
    </svg>

    <svg x="10%" viewBox="5 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#7FDBFF" />
    </svg>

    <svg x="90%" viewBox="5 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#7FDBFF" />
    </svg>
    
  </svg>
</div>
```